# Ant build fails in TFS 2015

Tags: ant, tfs, tfsbuild, tfs-2015

I have a java project and I'm gonna build it using a build agent running TFS 2015. I've installed JDK as well as ANT and also set the JAVA_HOME and ANT_HOME system variables. However the build process fails because of the following error message.

```
Unable to find Ant. Verify ANT_HOME is set and pointing to a valid Ant installation on the build agent: http://ant.apache.org/manual/install.html.
```

According to the instruction [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj155784(v=vs.120).aspx#Anchor_1), I should also install TFS build extensions, but I assume TFS 2015 does not require that and it comes with it by default.

I can figure out what the problem is.

Comment: sounds like ant executable is not on path

Comment: @DBug: it is, I mean I have also added the ANT_PATH/bin to the PATH variable. I can run ant command from the test agent and it runs.

Comment: it is Windows Server 2012 R2.

Comment: not familiar with tfs, but thought I'd suggest the obvious.  Sorry

Comment: Is %ANT_HOME%\lib set in CLASSPATH system variable?

Answer (score 0):

Ensure the user running the tfs build process has `%ANT_HOME%\bin` on it's `%PATH%`  Setting `ANT_HOME` is necessary, but not sufficient.

Comment: %PATH%\bin is already in the PATH under the system variables. Ir should be accessible by other users too, right?

Comment: you want to add %PATH%=%ANT_HOME%\bin

Comment: Sorry I meant %ANT_HOME%/bin exists under the system variables.